# TypeError: WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Here is a tiny part of my project structure

```
src
  features
    settings
       routes
          settings.routes.tsx
       settings.ts
  routes
    routes.config.ts
```

**settings.routes.tsx**

```
const SETTINGS_SCREEN: RouteItemDef = {
  id: "settings",
  path: SettingsPathsEnum.SETTINGS,
  navigationTitle: "settings.navigationTitle",
  component: SettingsRoutes,
  nestedRoutes: [
    {
      id: "projects",
      path: SettingsPathsEnum.PROJECTS,
      navigationTitle: "settingsProjects.navigationTitle",
      component: ProjectsScreen,
      layout: SidebarLayout, // using this line i'm getting error that I mentioned
    } 
   ]
 }

 export const SETTINGS_ROUTES = [SETTINGS_SCREEN];
```

**settings.ts**

```
// ROUTES
export * from "./routes/settings.routes";
```

**routes.config.ts**

```
import { AUTH_ROUTES } from "@app/features/auth/auth";
import { HOME_ROUTES } from "@app/features/home/home";
import { SETTINGS_ROUTES } from "@app/features/settings/settings";

export const ROOT_ROUTE = "/";

export const PUBLIC_LIST = [...AUTH_ROUTES];
export const PRIVATE_LIST = [...HOME_ROUTES, ...SETTINGS_ROUTES];
```

In `settings.routes.tsx` file when i use `layout` inside `nestedRoutes` array of object I get the error attached bellow

[image of error that i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sozo.jpg)

Comment: How do you define `HOME_ROUTES` and `SETTINGS_ROUTES`?

Comment: in `settings.routes.tsx` file

export const SETTINGS_ROUTES = [SETTINGS_SCREEN];